# How can we convert com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate to java.util.Date?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, datastax, cql3

I am working with dates.

Datastax's CQL cassandra API  `Row.getDate()` returns a `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate`.

I want to convert the `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate` object returned by the API to `java.util.Date`.  How can I do that?

Comment: This question as well as the following answer were very useful for me.

Comment: @adapt-dev In general, it's recommended to have question titles be... a question. Not a sentence which has an ungrammatical question mark after it. While the latter is common and accepted, editing a question specifically so that it has bad grammar, when it previously had perfect grammar, is not recommended.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`LocalDate.getMillisSinceEpoch()`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/core/LocalDate.html#getMillisSinceEpoch--) Javadoc says *Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970 GMT.* And, the [`Date(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) constructor Javadoc says *Allocates a `Date` object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.* So, given a `LocalDate` `ld` you should be able to do something like

```
Date d = new Date(ld.getMillisSinceEpoch());
```

Comment: It worked...Thanks...:)
Also Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(localDate.toString()); worked.

Comment: @Jayashree one other thing - the `getDate()` calls in the API used to return java.lang.Date.   The changed that in 2.2, but the call `getTimestamp()` will return a legit java Date rather than this Datastax thing.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer mentions either you can use

`Date d = new Date(row.getDate().getMillisSinceEpoch());`

or you can use `java.sql.Date.valueOf`

`Date d = java.sql.Date.valueOf(row.getDate().getString());`

**Instead of using `row.getDate` I personally use `row.getTimestamp` which returns Date object itself.**

`Date d = row.getTimestamp();`

Answer (score 0):

*you can follow below steps, to convert datastax LocalDate to Date:*

1. create LocateDate using Year, Month and Date from datastax LocalDate
   **datstax.Localdate dt = somevalue

   java.time.LocalDate ld = java.time.LocalDate.of(dt.getYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDay())**
2. format above LocalDate then you will get String type date
   **String dtt = ld.format(DateTimeFormater.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))**
3. then convert using SimpleDateFormat
   **Date tt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dtt)**

Enjoy :)