# How to use java.time.LocalDate in Cassandra query from Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

We have a table in Cassandra with column `start_time` of type `date`.

When we execute following code:

```
val resultRDD = inputRDD.joinWithCassandraTable(KEY_SPACE,TABLE)
   .where("start_time = ?", java.time.LocalDate.now)
```

We get following error:

```
com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConversionException: Cannot convert object 2016-10-13 of type class java.time.LocalDate to com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate.
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(TypeConverter.scala:45)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(TypeConverter.scala:43)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$LocalDateConverter$$anonfun$convertPF$14.applyOrElse(TypeConverter.scala:449)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$class.convert(TypeConverter.scala:43)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$LocalDateConverter$.com$datastax$spark$connector$types$NullableTypeConverter$$super$convert(TypeConverter.scala:439)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.NullableTypeConverter$class.convert(TypeConverter.scala:56)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$LocalDateConverter$.convert(TypeConverter.scala:439)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$OptionToNullConverter$$anonfun$convertPF$29.applyOrElse(TypeConverter.scala:788)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$class.convert(TypeConverter.scala:43)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$OptionToNullConverter.com$datastax$spark$connector$types$NullableTypeConverter$$super$convert(TypeConverter.scala:771)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.NullableTypeConverter$class.convert(TypeConverter.scala:56)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$OptionToNullConverter.convert(TypeConverter.scala:771)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.BoundStatementBuilder$$anonfun$8.apply(BoundStatementBuilder.scala:93)
```

I've tried to register custom converters according to [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/6_advanced_mapper.md):

```
object JavaLocalDateToCassandraLocalDateConverter extends TypeConverter[com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate] {
  def targetTypeTag = typeTag[com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate]
  def convertPF = { 
      case ld: java.time.LocalDate => com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate.fromYearMonthDay(ld.getYear, ld.getMonthValue, ld.getDayOfMonth) 
      case _ => com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate.fromYearMonthDay(1971, 1, 1) 
  }
}

object CassandraLocalDateToJavaLocalDateConverter extends TypeConverter[java.time.LocalDate] {
  def targetTypeTag = typeTag[java.time.LocalDate]
  def convertPF = { case ld: com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate => java.time.LocalDate.of(ld.getYear(), ld.getMonth(), ld.getDay()) 
                    case _ => java.time.LocalDate.now 
  }
}

TypeConverter.registerConverter(JavaLocalDateToCassandraLocalDateConverter)
TypeConverter.registerConverter(CassandraLocalDateToJavaLocalDateConverter)
```

But it didn't help.

How can I use JDK8 Date/Time classes in Cassandra queries executed from Spark?

Comment: How about passing DataStax date directly after inline conversion? You didn't like that?

Comment: Firstly - in other parts of code we use classes from JDK8 Date/Time so I would like not to conver it every time.
Secondy - even if I pass DataStax LocalDate I got
`object not serializable (class: com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate, value: 2016-10-13)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest thing to do in a where clause like this is to just call

```
sc
 .cassandraTable("test","test")
 .where("start_time = ?", java.time.LocalDate.now.toString)
 .collect`
```

And just pass in the string since that will be a well defined conversion.

There seems to be an issue in the TypeConverters where your converter is not taking precedence over the built in converter. I'll take a quick look.

--Edit--

It seems like the registered converters are not being properly transferred to the Executors. In Local mode the code works as expected which makes me think this is a serialization issue. I would open a ticket on the Spark Cassandra Connector for this issue.

Comment: Thank you for reply - it works! I though about this solution after @shankar response. But it looked a little bit suboptimal to me that I need to convert `java.time.LocalDate` to `String` and then `com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter.LocalDateConverter` converts it to `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra date format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`

so you can use the below code, if you are using Java 8 to convert Cassandra date to `LocalDate`, then you can do your logic.

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(cassandraDateTime, formatter);
```

Or you can convert LocalDate to Cassandra date format and check it.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html) Cassadra `date` format is described as `Date string, such as 2015-05-03`. Do I miss something?

Comment: @MarcinArmatys : Since you are using only Date not timestamp, please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295137/how-can-we-convert-com-datastax-driver-core-localdate-to-java-util-date